# Proof of $[p](x)≡x^p\operatorname{mod}p \Bbb{Z}_p$ for formal group of elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, formal-groups

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}_p$.
Let $ \hat{E}$ be formal group of $E$.

Let $[p](x)＝x＋_\hat{E}＋・・・＋_\hat{E}x$ (add by formal group law $p$ times).

**I want to know the proof of  $[p](x)≡x^p\operatorname{mod}p \Bbb{Z}_p$.**

First term of $[p](x)$ is just $px$, so what we need to look is term of degree more than 2.

I understand the definition of formal group of $E$ described in Silverman's book ' The arithmetic of elliptic curves'. But I'm having trouble how to gain the information about higher degree term of $[p](x)$.

Background : I was inspired another question in MO, and If I could understand this proof, I can say $ \hat{E}$ is Lubin-Tate formal group law.

Thanks to comments, this statement does not hold in general.
But Coats Wiles's article describes seemingly this statement
in
https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN356556735_0039?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B232%5D,%22pan%22:%7B%22x%22:0.413,%22y%22:0.884%7D,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.753%7D.
Where am I misunderstanding ? Certain similar true statement like $[p](x)≡x^pmodp\Bbb{Z}_p$ holds ?

Comment: That is just plainly wrong for curves with supersingular reduction as they will start with $x^{p^2}$ modulo $p$. But also for ordinary reduction there is no reason to think all terms after $x^p$ are divisible by $p$. Just take any example.

Comment: It is not even true that the coefficient in front of $x^p$ is $1$ modulo $p$.

Comment: https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN356556735_0039?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B232%5D,%22pan%22:%7B%22x%22:0.413,%22y%22:0.884%7D,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.753%7D

Comment: This article's page 228, Coates and wiles states $[p](x)≡x^pmodpo_p$, where am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: You missed the assumptions, like that $E$ has complex multiplication. Otherwise you have no element $\pi$ they use to justify the statement you are after. I think the article answers your question very well above the equality.

Comment: Hint : \pmod and the like work here.

Comment: Could you tell me what do you mean by \pmod?

Comment: I'm confused about what is the definition of $[π]$ in the article, and whether the subject extension is always Lubin tate if we admit it has CM.